# Creating a table 1 in R

Tags: r

I have one dataset, called `unchf_data`, it contains participants where some have answered a questionnaire and some have not. I want to make a descriptive table (table 1) where I have the columns (`Total`, `No answer`, `Answer`).

## Making new column subgroup, for a table 1. # if PREG column answered "Yes" or 1, then in final cohort.

```
`unchf_data2 <- unchf_data2[!(unchf_data2$PREG == "0"),]`# removing all where pregnancy is 0. If no pregnancy then no chance of having an APO.

    unchf_data2<- unchf_data2[!c(is.na(unchf_data2$HYPTPREG) == "TRUE" & 
                                   is.na(unchf_data2$DIABPREG) == "TRUE" &
                                   is.na(unchf_data2$BABYLT5LBS) == "TRUE" &
                                   is.na(unchf_data2$BORN3WKSERLY) == "TRUE" &
                                   is.na(unchf_data2$PREECLMP) == "TRUE" &
                                   is.na(unchf_data2$BABYGT9LBS) == "TRUE"),]  # removing all that have missing in all APO variables. 

`unchf_data2$subgroup <- 1` # creating new variable - subgroup which has 1 in all

    unchf_data2$subgroup <- factor(unchf_data2$subgroup, levels = c(1))

`subgroup2 <- unchf_data2$subgroup` # making the new vector from subgroup variable

library(qpcR)
unchf_data <- qpcR:::cbind.na(subgroup2, unchf_data)  # Binds our new vector with length of 10375 to our data set with length of 44174, filling in NA values for everything longer than the vector. 


unchf_data$subgroup2[is.na(unchf_data$subgroup2) == "TRUE"] <- 0 # recoding all NA values to 0
unchf_data$subgroup2 <- factor(unchf_data$subgroup2, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No answer", "Answer")) # converting variable to factor. 

summary(unchf_data$subgroup2) # No answer 33799, Answer 10375
```

My problem now is that apparently the new subgroup2 variable does not line up with the original dataset. 
Is there another way I can do this? 
The reason I want a new variable in the dataset is because I'm using the UnivariateTable function from the Publish Package

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please include all non-standard libraries that you have loaded (eg. where does `cbind.na` come from?).